# 5.0.0-21 kernel update causing desktop and mouse problems

Tags: upgrade, kernel

The latest update for Ubuntu Studio on July 23 2019 is causing memory problems. (Kernel 5.0.0-21) My desktop settings do not fully load when booting up, and the mouse exhibits heavy lag. When I boot using a previous kernel (5.0.0-20) all my desktop settings, including the Nvidia settings load as expected, and everything runs fine. It's as if certain items aren't loading into memory on startup as they should. I recently cloned everything from a HDD to a SSD without a glitch and everything was running extremely well until the update on July 23.
My Nvidia driver is the recommended 418 as I've been asked to clarify this.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96611/discussion-on-question-by-john-5-0-0-21-kernel-update-causing-desktop-and-mouse).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to document the solution...

From the comments...

Figured out what the problem was. And I was right in thinking that it was a memory conflict of some sort. In BIOS, I had XMP enabled which automatically set my ram to run at it's maximum speed of 1600 (a bit of overclocking in a sense). I've toned it back down to 1333 and now when I boot up using the latest 5.0.0-21 kernel everything is at it should be.