# Finally updated laptop from Windows 10 to Ubuntu 18.04; the keyboard and mouse no longer works after getting to the lock screen

Tags: 18.04, keyboard

I have gone through the process mentioned in a 2017 post: [Updated from 16.04 to 16.10; the keyboard and mouse no longer works after getting to the lock screen](https://askubuntu.com/questions/908918/updated-from-16-04-to-16-10-the-keyboard-and-mouse-no-longer-works-after-gettin)

I can get the mouse working, and then turn on the on-screen keyboard. But when I restart/turn off/ log out, I lose the mouse control and have to go through all the steps again.

Keyboard works in startup, and able to access CL in recovery mode. Read some errors while in recovery mode CL, so when I had logged into the system (and using the on-screen keyboard) I input the commands mentioned in previous posts.

**Commands previously tried but not working:**

- `sudo apt install xserver-xorg-input-all`
- `apt full-upgrade -y && apt install -y ubuntu-desktop && apt install xserver-xorg-input-all`
- `sudo apt-get install --reinstall xserver-xorg-input-all`
- `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`
- `apt-get update && apt-get dist-upgrade && update-usbids`

I only have one kernel option under recovery mode.

Any assistance would be appreciated. At this point, I am tempted to just reload my Ubuntu image and not select to update to the latest version. The original image allowed my keyboard and mouse to work.

Comment: What is your kernel version now? Use `uname -r` to reveal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The same problem was reported yesterday:

- [5.0.0-21 kernel update causing desktop and mouse problems](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1160548/5-0-0-21-kernel-update-causing-desktop-and-mouse-problems)

At the same time a related kernel problem was reported:

- [Software Updater Kernel Update broke package manager - Cannot install linux-modules-extra-5.0.0-21-generic](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1160549/software-updater-kernel-update-broke-package-manager-cannot-install-linux-modu/1160555#1160555)

Hopefully this will be fixed in the next Ubuntu kernel update `5.0.0-21` but in the meantime use kernel `5.0.0-20`. If you want to avoid reinstalling Ubuntu you can manually install the previous Linux Mainline/Stable kernel with these instructions:

- [How to update kernel to the latest mainline version without any Distro-upgrade?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/119080/how-to-update-kernel-to-the-latest-mainline-version-without-any-distro-upgrade/885165#885165)

The kernel before `5.0.0-21` in Ubuntu Speak is `5.1.16` or `4.19.59` in Linux Speak. When looking at the mainline kernels the important thing to remember is the dates. Anything dated July 21-23 is new one with bugs, anything around July 14 is the previous version:

[image: Ubuntu Mainline Kernels July 23.png]

Comment: Viola!! I downloaded version from 6.30.19, installed and it works now!  Thank you very much, WinEunuuchs2Unix.

Comment: Having the same problem in February 2021 so obviously not fixed yet or continuing in newer kernels. However if a cant access the system at all, no terminal and no icons I guess its another install. which kernel would you recommend please. If no success I will return to 18.04 LTS until its sorted. A whole day will be lost by tomorrow afternoon. I have dual screens and it also annoying the opportunity to have icons on both screens has also disappeared. Please help. Thank you